# Modify class member though operator override with scalar argument

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am writing a class that has a `std::vector` as member, and I'd like to be able to modify its data in bulk by using default operators `+`/`+=`, `*`/`*=`, etc taking a scalar as argument, e.g.

```
MyClass<float> obj;
obj += 4.0;
```

I'm tring to define the operator overload as:

```
template <class _type> 
matrix2D<_type>& matrix2D<_type>::operator=(matrix2D<_type> _mat){
    std::swap(_mat,*this);
    return *this;
};

template <class _type>
template <typename _input_type>
myClass<_type> myClass<_type>::operator*(_input_type _val) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) data[i] *= _val; 
    return *this;
};

template <class _type>
template <typename _input_type>
myClass<_type> myClass<_type>::operator*=(_input_type _val) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) data[i] *= _val; 
    return *this;
};
```

I get no compile or runtime errors, but the values remain unchanged. I've tried to a multitude of different types of return values (`MyClass&`, `void`) and passing a `myClass` object as argument. What am I missing?

Comment: What you seem to want already exists as [`std::valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray).

Comment: As for a possible reasons for your problem, assignment operators are supposed to return `*this` *by reference*. And your `operator*` is wrong as well, it should not modify `this` or its members. I suggest you read e.g. [this operator overloading reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), especially look closer at [the canonical implementations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations). And of course [read a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: From what I saw, your instance is modified (even for `operator*` :-/ ).

Comment: I was following the guidelines in [here](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html). I've tried return the class object by reference - the result is the same. I don't understand exactly why I should not modify `this`?

Comment: If you have `a = b * c`, should either `b` or `c` be modified? No, that's not how multiplication (other other arithmetic operations) work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude fair enough, that should be the case for the `*` operator. But what about the compound `*=`?

Comment: No that would of course need to modify the recipient. `a *= b` would indeed modify `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write this naive;y, or it's going to be the slowest implementation the world has seen. And definitely don't use `std::val_array`, as it is not optimised with any compiler I know of. It was dead in the water with it's comception There is a Matrix class in my PhD work, if you care get inspired there: https://github.com/kvahed/codeare/blob/master/src/matrix/Matrix.hpp

As a rule of thumb stick to `std::vector` and use the functionality in `<algorithm>` like `std::accumulate`, `std::transform`, .... And always implement the assignment version of the operator and use that every where else.

So for example to cover both scalar and matrix elementwise multiplication:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
  public:
  ...
  Matrix<T>& operator*=(const T& t) {
    if (t != T(1)) {
      std::transform(
        v_.begin(), v_.end(), v_.begin(), std::bind2nd(std::multiplies<T>(), t));
    }
    return *this;
  }
  Matrix<T>& operator*=(const Matrix<T>& m) {
    std::transform(
      v_.begin(), v_.end(), m.begin(), v_.begin(), std::multiplies<T>()));
    return *this;
  }
  template<typename S>
  Matrix<T> operator* (const S& s) {
    return *this *= s;
  }
  ...
  private:
    std::vector<T> v_;
}
```

But this is neglecting SIMD instruction sets your CPU will be capable of:
https://github.com/kvahed/codeare/blob/master/src/matrix/SIMDTraits.hpp

But there are some stuff that you should keep in mind that turn out to be non-trivial. Particularly, when your matrices are not allocated on the heap, memory can be unaligned. This will kill you entirely. Calculating by hand is faster then. 
https://github.com/kvahed/codeare/blob/master/src/matrix/Allocator.hpp

Seriously, getting what you want to build right is a lot of work and test code.

TLDR: If you are looking for naive implementation use `<algorithm>` stay clear of `val_array`. Feel free to use my stuff. If you got questions, anytime.